# PowerShell Import-Excel Module - Set Autofilter Criteria

Tags: excel, powershell, autofilter

I'm trying to use the Import-Excel module to set the autofilter criteria for a specific column in an Excel file.

Here's the base of what I have:

```
        $excelPkg   = Open-ExcelPackage -Path ('{0}\{1}' -f ($FilePath, $File_Name))
        $excelSheet = $excelPkg.Workbook.Worksheets[$ExcelSheetName]
        $excelSheet.Cells[$FilterRange].AutoFilter = $true
```

This works, as far as enabling the autofilter option in the Excel file, but how do I set the criteria?

In my example, I have a column that will either have a Y or N value. I want to enable the autofilter and then set it so that by default only rows where that column's value = Y are displayed.

Is this possible with the Import-Excel module? I can find all kinds of examples when using the COM object method, but not really finding anything applicable to this module.